# Not Calling NHibernate Session Close

Tags: nhibernate, memory-leaks

I'm looking at some code that I know has a memory leak and I think I know why. however; I am curious about the bloody details.

At the beginning of a request there is a call to session.OpenSession(); in order to get an ISession but at the end of the request there is no call session.Close(); and/or session.Dispose();

What objects are staying in memory? Are the "entities" hanging around? What features of NHibernate are being lost? Will these objects every get garbage collected?

Comment: You lose features of NHibernate when you close the session.

Comment: At the end of a http, wcf or winforms form close I need to close the session. I can't and don't want to close it in the middle, just what if I don't close it at whatever "end" my request has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't close the session, all the entities referenced there, and all the supporting data structures stay there until it's garbage collected.

So, closing the session **must** be done at the end of the request, whether it was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the singleton pattern